# Filtering questions with two tags - getting new activity entries with one of the tags on them

Tags: bug

In Stack Overflow, I'm filtering questions tagged with both **`[youtube]`** and **`[python]`** tags; when new entries appears in the search results - i.e: *3 questions with new activity* - and press the link for show the new entries, those entries are only questions with **`[python]`** tag on them.

You can follow this [link with the filters on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube+python), or follow these steps for reproduce this *bug*:

- In the **`search`** bar type: **`[youtube] [python]`** and press *Enter*.
- Wait a few seconds and you'll see the link with the legend: *X questions with new activity*. Click that link.
- The new entries loaded are actually questions with **`[python]`** tag on them, not with the tags set in the search bar.

I do consider this behaviour as a bug, but, I want to share this finding and know if anyone else has seen a similar problem with the search feature.

Also, the number of results (*Example: 818 questions*) is not updated when the *X questions with new activity* link is clicked.

Comment: I observe the same behaviour. It does appear to be a bug.

Comment: @rene, you're right, thanks for share the link. In that case, can you post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Already reported: [Has the behaviour of combined tags search changed?](/q/393969/4642212).